# python vscode ImportError: No module named simplejson

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, simplejson

i have import simplejson in my code, and installed using pip install simplejson using python3
so as i checked, it perfectly runs in my terminal opening the file but when i try to build in VScode, it shows an error like,
[see the error in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hBpg.png) as

`> Executing task: python /Users/Tony/Documents/python3.9/helloworld.py <

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Tony/Documents/python3.9/helloworld.py", line 1, in 
import simplejson as json
ImportError: No module named simplejson
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'python /Users/Tony/Documents/python3.9/helloworld.py'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).

but it still runs on my terminal. and if i check the pip list, simplejson is still there and i also tried to use different version of python too.

and I have activated the virtual environment [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icjzs.png)
and i am using the last one which i recently activated.

please help me to find the error. i don’t really know where to fix thanks

Comment: You are aware that simplejson is bo more than an externally maintained version of the json module built into the standard library? It was a thing in early Python 2 versions. But nowadays you should consider using the json module.

Comment: thank you for the info! I’m very new to python and just following the steps from the tutorial which i paid... so .. :( but thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced this process and hope the following steps could help you

1.Activate the venv and install `simplejson`;

2.Run the `helloworld.py` in Terminal to make sure the script no error;

[image]

3.Configure the `tasks.json`, pay attention to use the **venv's pythonpath**;

```
"version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run python file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/venv's pythonpath/ helloworld.py",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

4.Tasks:Run Task;

[image]

Comment: Happy that my answer helps you, it's appreciated that if you can mark it.

Comment: :) can i ask one more question? what if i want to access with the whole folder with python files? like not only the helloworld.py file. do i need to include the whole project directory?

Comment: Add `"env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
    },
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` in launch.json, the parameter **workspaceFolder** means the path of the folder opened in VS Code, which is the whole current project folder.